# returning null array from php file

Tags: php, android

i am sending a value from my android app (value) using

httpClient, i need to fetch a row from DB according to that value, when i try it

it returns a null array (json array), but if i use static value like name, for

example:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column= 'name'");
```

i get the array successfully, here is the php file, please help

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass"); 

if (!$con) {
    die("Could not connected".mysql_error());
} else {
    mysql_select_db("database",$con);

    if (!empty($_POST['value'])) {

      $value=$_POST['value'];
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column= '$value'");

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $output[]=$row;
      }

      print(json_encode($output));
      mysql_close($con);
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: 1. `mysql` is deprecated. Use `mysqli` instead. 2. Escape `$value` before inserting into the query.

Comment: how to escape it before?

Comment: I think you are not getting the value of that post variable.

Comment: @ZaidNajjar, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string($value); but I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: well, i guess php works fine except the value isnt there :/

Comment: but my code works perfectly and sent it to php

Comment: how can i check the value of this variable?

Comment: You can probably put watch on your android code where you sending that value to the server.

Comment: ya i idid that , and it sent the value , but is this the right way to write php code to recieve avalue and check it in sql?

Comment: i dont know much php sorry XD

Comment: yes, this is the right way of php to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$output = array();
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

{
  $output[$i]=$row;
  $i++;
}   
print(json_encode($output));
```

Comment: you mean    $output = new array();  then   $output = $row;

Comment: `new array()` in PHP?!

Comment: sorry my mistake its only `array();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create array before while loop as following.

```
$output = array();
```

Following is your correct code, I am assuming that you are getting value in your post variable.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass"); 
if(!$con)
{
 die("Could not connected".mysql_error());
}
else
{
  mysql_select_db("database",$con);
  if(!empty($_POST['value']))
  {
   $value=$_POST['value'];
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column= '$value'");
   $output = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
     $output[]=$row;
   }
   print(json_encode($output));
   mysql_close($con);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$a[]= 10` creates `$a` array automatically. He doesn't need to initialize array in PHP.